# Pods stay in ContainerCreating state with "Failed create pod sandbox" message

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops, kubernetes-pod

Performed an upgrade of K8S AWS cluster from 1.8.4 to 1.9.8 using kops.

All "development" pods and some pods from kube-system namespace (cluster-autoscaler, kube-dns, kube-dns-autoscaler, kubernetes-dashboard, heapster) stuck in "*ContainerCreating*" state.

Pods describe command shows message:  "*Failed create pod sandbox*" and "*Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.*"

Any ideas what could be the reason for such behavior or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is becoming [a FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkubernetes%5D+sandbox)

But Pod sandbox errors are almost always [CNI failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427073/failed-create-pod-sandbox-pod-error-in-aws-kubernetes-cluster), which goes double for your situation since I don't know that 1.8 even used [CNI](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni#readme)